# Rails Callback before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models `Employee` and `Company`. In the `Employee` model i have a `before_create` callback, but when doing `@company.employees.create(params)`, the callback is not fired. What are my options for making the callback work? I use the `before_create` because i only wan't it to fire the first time, the object is created.

Comment: well, that should have worked, are you sure the employee is validated and persisted? Or try before_save, :on => :create, even though I guess u'll run into the same issue.

Comment: before_validation :foo, :on => :create works. Apparently validations happen before anything else.

Comment: before_validations work before validation, before_create work after validation, if the object is valid. Callback chain available here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html make sure your employee is valid.